# Have a popup menu on a borderless form

Tags: vb6, popupmenu

How to add a popup menu on a VB 6.0 borderless form?

Every time I add a menu, the border reappears, even when `BorderStyle` is set to `vbBSNone` and the menu is hidden.

Comment: What does the border look like?  Dotted line?  Can you post an image?

Comment: i mean the border of a VB form along with the title bar.

Comment: Hhhmmm... can you have a borderless form with a title bar?  I don't think so...

Comment: i guess you didnt understand what i m trying to say, open vb, create a new form, set its border to none from the properties, now show me how to add a right-click popup menu on the form.

Comment: I don't actually have VB6 on my machine any more -- just answering based on my past experience with it (more than 12-13 years ago I'm afraid).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's doable, but somewhat unsatisfying (to me). By having any menu properties in a form, the border will default back to visible. There are, however, a few workarounds:

1) The method I think you'll prefer involves making a second form that you'll never really "use" or see. Put the menu on that second form, and then call that menu from the form you actually want to use. Assuming you're using `Form_MouseDown` to call this, here's the code:

```
Private Sub Form_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button And vbRightButton Then PopupMenu Form2.mnuYourMenu
End sub
```

You will have to remember to unload this second form from memory, however.

2) Another way, only using the first form, would be to set the form's `ControlBox` to `False` and to leave the `Caption` property blank. This "removes" the border when `BorderStyle` is set to 0... I put removes in quotes because it will unfortunately leave behind a 1-pixel black line. It doesn't look bad, but it might not be a viable solution for you.

3) The final way, which I read about but haven't done anything with myself, would be to use the `CreatePopupMenu` API, found at http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/CreatePopupMenu.shtml

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have to admit that this is not a solution that I was expected, however, it works

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else who comes here looking for an answer to this problem, here is a very simple API method that works:

Declarations:

```
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Const GWL_STYLE = -16, WS_BORDER = &H800000
```

In Form_Load:

```
SetWindowLong Me.hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(Me.hwnd, GWL_STYLE) And Not WS_BORDER
```

Comment: Note that this does something different as it changes the effective position of the client area (VB moves the form to take into account the border/title). You also need to remove `WS_THICKFRAME` and the `WS_DLGFRAME` styles to end up with no border at all.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible.  Set the form's BorderStyle to None, Caption to an empty string, ControlBox, MaxButton MinButton to False.   Then, using VB6's menu editor, create a top-level menu named "mnuPopup," and set its Visible property to False.  Create the rest of the menu as submenus to that top-level menu, setting their Visible properties to True.  Then, in the code for the form, you can display the menu with `PopupMenu menuPopup`.  It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: this would bring the border back to visible.